# Cascade Type.ALL not working

Tags: jpa-2.0, hsqldb

I have set CascadeType.ALL in my entity relation, but it works partially whenevr I persist an entity.

Ex : 
`   Member entity :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="member", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
private List<ContactInfo> contactInfos;
```

and ContactInfo entity :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="MEMBERID")
private Member member;
```

`

`Member` details and also `ContactInfo` data are persisted. But `Member.Id` is not updated in `ContactInfo` table as I have nullable foreignkey constraint in `ContactInfo` table.

How would I make JPA to automatically update Member.Id in ContactInfo also whenever I persist Member?

Regards,

Satya

Comment: Whatever I try, nothing works. Any suggestion would be of great help. I use Hibernate implementation and do not use hibernate session for persisting, so hopefully CascadeType.ALL should work.

Comment: Perhaps you could post your Member.Id declaration along with the annotation so we could have a better picture of your problem ? And also, please explain why you need to update the Id field ? Is the Id field the primary key of Member entity ?

Answer (score 5):

If you use the CascadeType.ALL to only cascade the member in the ContactInfo, then the Member is the owning side. You have to remove the mappedby, duplicate the @JoinColumn info and put the @ManyToOne side as non-insertable and non-updatable. This will tell hibernate that the MEMBERID of CONTACTINFO must be updated when saving a MEMBER.

Here is the mapping:

Member entity :

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="MEMBERID") //we need to duplicate the physical information
private List<ContactInfo> contactInfos;
```

Contact entity :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="MEMBERID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Member member;
```

[Reference Hibernate Section 2.2.5.3.1.1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association)

Comment: Almost after a year...Yes I will surely try this whenever I find the time. Thanks a lot for the update and link :)